# Is this sentence grammatically correct, clear and idiomatic, "sweep all the stuff into the dustpan"?

Tags: meaning

The presenter is cleaning the floor.

[image]

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/OyIytwRIKTM?t=59) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> sweep all the and to the dustpan

It is obviously a incorrect sentence in terms of written english.

Is it correct if I rewrite that sentence as this?

> sweep all the stuff into the dustpan

in other words, Is this sentence grammatically correct, clear and idiomatic, "sweep all the stuff into the dustpan"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think she says

> sweep all that into the dustpan

Your sentence is also fine.